# how to add "-env ERL_LIBS XXX" for "ct_run" command?

Tags: erlang

I have used `"rebar generate"` to create the package and move package to the test pc for running.

But when running the common test suite, I don't know how to `"-env ERL_LIBS XXX"` with `"ct_run"` command.

How to correct it?

```
ct_run -dir /home/peter/gate-0.0.1.20/lib/gate-0.0.1.20/ct -suite gate_test_data_SUITE.erl -erl_args -- -env ERL_LIBS gate-0.0.1.20/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable also works for the environment. Have you tried running the command as `ERL_LIBS gate-0.0.1.20/lib ct_run -dir /home/peter/gate-0.0.1.20/lib/gate-0.0.1.20/ct -suite gate_test_data_SUITE.erl` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your remind. I try it and found for ERL_LIBS, it is necessary to use absolute path for ct_path may change current path internally. It works now!